# How can I in typescript access to a explicit argument from yargs?

Tags: typescript, yargs

The concept of yargs is nice.

```
const argv = yargs.options({
    env: {
        alias: 'e',
        choices: ['dev', 'prod'] as const,
        demandOption: true,
        description: 'app environment'
    }
})
    .argv;

console.log(argv);
```

But if I check argv.env explicit, typescript say: There is no argv.env. How can I solve this in typescript?

```
if(argv.env == "dev"){ // not work in typescript
   ...
}
```

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/typescript.md?

Answer (score 2):

This work (if the program not using any asynchronous commands):

```
import yargs from 'yargs/yargs'; // <== very important !!!

const argv2 = yargs(process.argv.slice(2)).options({
    env: {
        alias: 'e',
        choices: ['dev', 'prod'] as const,
        demandOption: true,
        description: 'app environment'
    }
})
    .parseSync();

console.log(argv2.env);
```

Comment: Actually, `parseSync()` method solved it!